# Problems while updating Fasterxml jackson databind to version 2.14.0-rc1

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, jackson-databind, fasterxml

**There are vulnerabilities in fasterXML jackson-databind version I am currently using, Vulnerabilities are : CVE - 2022-42003, CVE - 2022-42004**

I searched on intelliJ and codebase, changed version in all components, pom.xml file, which I could find manually through search on intellij, but when I saw report it is giving errors for a lot of components, even which doesn't have jackson-databind directly mentioned in pom file, so I checked Camel Fm component, in its Pom file, I found camel-jackson, which has com.fasterxml.jackson-databind as compile dependency.

So I have two questions,

1. first how do I fix this dependency, I
   have not made any change to camel fm pom file, should I upgrade its
   camel-jackson version, or is there any other way because jackson-databind is not
   present in its pom section remember, vulnerabilities issue is for
   jackson-databind, but I don't know how to make change for compile
   dependency which also have to be handled.
2. How do I find other components which might have
   jackson-databind as compile dependency, which might need to be
   changed just as fm camel (can't use
   plugins or third party software in my work environment)

Comment: I'm updating from 2.7.9.7 but it seems like there's no easy/clear path